# XML transformation in Erlang

Tags: xml, erlang, transform

I have the following XML:

```
<test>
    <something name="test">
        <todo>Something is here!</todo>
    </something>
    <mytag id="myID">!!!!</mytag>
    <todo>Hello, world</todo>
</test>
```

And I need to replace the content of a tag that has `id="myID"` and get:

```
<test>
    <something name="test">
        <todo>Something is here!</todo>
    </something>
    <mytag id="myID">**MY NEW STRING IS HERE**</mytag>
    <todo>Hello, world</todo>
</test>
```

Is there any standard way to achieve it? I know that [xmerl_xs](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/xmerl/xmerl_xs_examples.html) is an Erlang way of XML transformation. But it cannot be used to solve my problem.

And I only managed to get `<mytag id="myID">**MY NEW STRING IS HERE**</mytag>` using Xmerl. My code:

```
{ RootEl, _Rest } = xmerl_scan:string(Template),
[Match|_] = xmerl_xpath:string("//*[@id='myID']", RootEl),
% Pack new content to the container
Result = Match#xmlElement { content="**MY NEW STRING IS HERE**" }
```

Is it only possible with non-standard libraries ([Sablotron](http://forum.trapexit.org/viewtopic.php?p=30202) and others)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used that library, but I think xmerl_lib:mapxml/2 is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [`erlsom`](http://erlsom.sourceforge.net/) library ? It could provide a much flexible way.